# Hide gridlines with the Google Sheets API in Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread, gspread-formatting

I want to remove all the gridlines in my google sheet. I think I need to use batchupdate in combination with a JSON request that sets the hideGridlines in gridProperties to True but I can't seem to get it to work.

Anyone knows how to do this?

This is what I have so far but it gives an error about not having a sheet name.

```
     [{
         'updateSheetProperties': {
                "fields": "*",
                "properties": {
                    "gridProperties": {
                        "hideGridlines": True,
                    },
                    "sheetId": self.sheet.id,
                },
            },
        }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that in your showing request body, it is required to modify the value of `fields` as follows.

#### From:

```
"fields": "*",
```

#### To:

```
"fields": "gridProperties.hideGridlines",
```

#### Reference:

- [UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatesheetpropertiesrequest)